# selenium find element in a while loop in java

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium, while-loop

So, I have a selenium webdriver command that is a condition for the while loop as shown here:

```
            while (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[action='cancel']")).isDisplayed() == true){
            driver.navigate().refresh();

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            driver.findElement(By.id("479510558845313")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamusernameinput);

            driver.findElement(By.id("263795143794707")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamcommentinput);

            driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_4")).sendKeys(x);
            driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
        }

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Okay')]")).click();
        killFirefox();
```

So, my problem is that when the condition is false, it does not skip the while loop and go to what's below it. It tries to do this : `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[action='cancel']"))` which makes the program fail. How do I make it skip it when it's false ands go to what's out of the loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the case when the element is not present before checking if it's visible:

```
while (true){
    WebElement button = null;
    try {
      button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[action='cancel']"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
      break;   // button is missing, exit the loop
    }
    if (button.isDisplayed() == false) {
      break;   // button is hidden, exit the loop
    }

    driver.navigate().refresh();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    driver.findElement(By.id("479510558845313")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamusernameinput);

    driver.findElement(By.id("263795143794707")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamcommentinput);

    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_4")).sendKeys(x);
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how the program failed, but I'm assuming that the indicated findElement returned a null?

I suggest that you restructure your loop so that you do something like (code is not tested):

```
while (true) {
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    WebElement cancelButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[action='cancel']"));
    if (cancelButton != null and cancelButton.isDisplayed()) {
        ... the stuff to do if it is displayed
    } else {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that but it gives me this error `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[action='cancel']"}` I'll try what you suggested and get back to you.

Comment: Ah!  in that case, the issue is that the cancel button cannot be found, so you 'll need a try/catch block inside your while statement to catch the NoSuchElementException and break when that happens.